# How to pick out/trim part of a string using Shell

Tags: linux, string, shell, date

I am trying to trim this, which is stored in a variable called $line.

```
[2012-06-18 10:37:09,026 (there is a lot of text after this, i just cut it out)
```

I am new to shell scripting and this is the code that i have

```
errortime= $line | cut -c2-10;
```

it is giving me an error, what is the correct code to pull the date out of the variable $line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you want:

```
errortime=`echo $line | cut -c2-20`
```

instead?

---

Edit:
If you are using ksh, that line needs to look like this:

```
errortime=$(echo $line | cut -c2-20)
```

Comment: ./test2zach.sh[11]: echo $line | cut -c2-10:  not found --- that is the error i get with that change

Comment: @zach What shell are you using? It assigns `errortime` with the result of `echo $line | cut -c2-20`, which is the value of `$line` applied with `cut -c2-20`

Comment: @ Jon Lin that is what i thought too. I will check on my shell. i know i am using putty, but let me check on some more details

Comment: i did echo $SHELL and it return /bin/ksh. i have no idea what that means, but the elders of the internet said that is how i find out my version of shell

Comment: @zach Do you not have a `#!` line at the beginning of test2zach.sh? But if you are using ksh, see edit

Comment: Brillant! i have #!/bin/ksh at the top. I made the edit mentioned above and it work like a snake charm. Is there somewhere i can find the different types of Shell?

Comment: @zach "Is there somewhere i can find the different types of Shell?" You can try googling `choosing your shell` to get some articles about different shells